# Finding files of fixed length

Tags: linux, grep, find

I am trying to find file names that start with the letter 'a' and are of length 6. I have tried many variations, the latest one being:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -regex "^[a]" > grep {6}
```

However I get an error message of:

```
find: paths must precede expression: {6}
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following command which is using *extended posix regexes*:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/a.{5}'
```

Let me explain the pattern from the end:

- `.{5}` matches five arbitrary characters
- `a` matches a literal `a`
- the `/` matches the path delimiter right before the filename
- `.*` is the path, in this case `/usr/bin`

---

Btw, a simple command which does not even require a special regex engine would be:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -regex '.*/a.....'
```

- `$` is the end of the filename
- `.....` are five arbitrary characters
- `a` is a literal `a`
- `.*/` is the preceding path

---

Another thing. While your regex is wrong and `grep` is not required at all, why do you get this strange error message?

You are using `find ... > grep` where I think you wanted to use `find ... | grep`. Note that `>` will redirect the output of the `find` command to a *file*. In this case a file named `grep`. If you want to redirect the output of the `find` command into the input of a `grep` *command* you need to use the pipe symbol `find ... | grep`.

A `> filename` redirection can appear anywhere in a command line, it does not necessarily have to be at the end. That' why `{6}` is interpreted as the last argument to `find`. Since this argument is not expected, `find` supposed that you accidentally passed a search path at the end, which is a common mistake. That's why the message.

Answer (score 4):

Without any regexes, just globbing:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -name 'a?????'
```

References:

- Findutils manual: [Shell pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html)
- Bash manual, [Filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) and [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)